# While searching directory, only first instance of specified file name is shown

Tags: java, file, search, directory

I am attempting to search a directory chosen by the user for any and all files. There is an option to search for a specific string of characters and have only file names with instances of these characters appear on the screen. When I run this program, however, no text (except the default specified by using JTextArea constructor) appears on the screen. If possible, I would truly appreciate it if someone helps me debug.

```
package comp.search.direct;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SearchInitializer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static JButton button;
    public static JTextArea ta;
    public static JTextField tf;
    public static JPanel pane, pane2, pane3;
    public static JLabel label;
    public static JCheckBox jcb;
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchInitializer sci = new SearchInitializer();
    }

    public SearchInitializer() {
    super("Search Directory");
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    button = new JButton("Search Directory");

    ta = new JTextArea("File Names:");
    ta.setEditable(false);

    tf = new JTextField(10);

    label = new JLabel("Find:");

    jcb = new JCheckBox("Append Text");

    pane2 = new JPanel();
    pane2.add(label);
    pane2.add(tf);

    pane3 = new JPanel();
    pane3.add(button);
    pane3.add(jcb);

    pane.add(pane3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pane.add(pane2, BorderLayout.EAST);

    addActionListeners();

    getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void searchDirectory(File folder, JTextField find, JTextArea ta, ArrayList<String> arg) {
    arg.clear();
    for (File fileentry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (find.getText() == null) {
        if (fileentry.isDirectory()) {
            searchDirectory(fileentry, find, ta, arg);
        } else {
            if (!fileentry.getName().endsWith(".lnk"))
            ta.append("\n" + fileentry.getName());
        }
        } else {
        if (fileentry.isDirectory()) {
            searchDirectory(fileentry, find, ta, arg);
        } else {
            if (!fileentry.getName().contains(find.getText()))
            return;
            else {
            if (arg.contains(fileentry.getName())) {
                ta.append("\n" + fileentry.getName());
                arg.add(fileentry.getName());
                searchDirectory(folder, find, ta, arg);
                System.out.println(fileentry.getName()); // Testing purposes only
            } else {
                return;
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }

    public void addActionListeners() {
    button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if (fc.showDialog(SearchInitializer.this, "Select") ==     JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        searchDirectory(new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()), tf, ta, filenames);
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put irrelevant code in your questions.

Comment: If I believed this code to be irrelevant, I wouldn't have included it. I was trying to help by including as much code as possible. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably here:

```
        if (arg.contains(fileentry.getName())) {
            ta.append("\n" + fileentry.getName());
            arg.add(fileentry.getName());
            searchDirectory(folder, find, ta, arg);
            System.out.println(fileentry.getName()); // Testing purposes only
        } else {
            return;
        }
```

You're telling it to add an entry to the `ArrayList` only if it's already there.  Because of this logic, there's no way your `ArrayList` will ever be anything other than empty.

Comment: I recieve a stack overflow by changing
    if (arg.contains(fileentry.getName())) {
to
    if (!arg.contains(fileentry.getName())) {
As if its still not adding the file name

Comment: @fmi11 you have a recursive call that doesn't belong.

Comment: It's recursive because i need it to search for the next instance of the specified characters. Without calling the method again, it only gives me the first instance.

Comment: @fmi11 When you call it recursively with the same `folder` argument, the recursive call starts with `folder.listFiles()`, and that will start over from the beginning, not where the iterator in the caller left off.  Won't the `for` loop find the remaining instances?  Also, please make sure you're not cutting off the `for` loop too early with your `return` statements.  I haven't studied this thoroughly, but I think your logic needs some rethinking.  You shouldn't be using recursion except to go into subfolders.

Comment: That did it. Once I removed the return statements, it processed the other files. I was cutting off the for loop. I appreciate your help and if I had more reputation I would give you a vote.